# How do I select unique values in a single column with multiple column selected?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

the query is actually fine and running but it doesn't select distinct the column A.CONTRACT_NUMBER.

This is the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.CONTRACT_NUMBER
, A.DTIME_SIGNATURE
, A.ID_CUID
, A.CLIENT_SEGMENT
, A.CLIENT_GENDER
, A.CLIENT_AGE
, A.CNT_SIGNED
, A.AMT_SIGNED
, A.INSTALMENTS
, A.PRODUCT
, B.AMT_INTEREST_INCOME
  FROM DM_SALES.V_SALES_DM_DATA A
  LEFT JOIN DM_FIN.FIN_LTV_DATAMART B ON A.CONTRACT_NUMBER = B.CONTRACT_NUMBER
  WHERE 1=1
  AND A.CONTRACT_STATE <> 'Cancelled' 
  AND a.cnt_signed=1 
  AND A.LOAN_TYPE = 'Consumer Loan'
  AND (TRUNC(A.DTIME_SIGNATURE) BETWEEN DATE'2022-08-01' AND DATE '2022-08-31')
  GROUP BY A.CONTRACT_NUMBER
  ORDER BY A.DTIME_SIGNATURE
;
```

It runs normally but after checking the data, there are still repeated values in the A.CONTRACT_NUMBER column. A.CONTRACT_NUMBER is like the primary key column and I'd like to select unique values to that column

Thanks! :D

Comment: DISTINCT works with all columns in your SELECT statement, not a single column

Comment: `distinct` applies to the entire select list, not to any individual column; if two rows have all values exactly the same then only one will be returned. If you showed a `contract_number` once, when it currently has multiple rows, then which values would you show in all the other columns in that single row? The entire row for the most recent `dtime_signature`?

Comment: There seem to be multiple B rows per A row. But you want an A row appear only once in your result. So which B.AMT_INTEREST_INCOME do you want to show? The average maybe? Or the sum? As is, your query is invalid, because you cannot group by A.CONTRACT_NUMBER and select B.AMT_INTEREST_INCOME for that reason. You haven't told the DBMS which B.AMT_INTEREST_INCOME.

Comment: Have I understood this correctly? CONTRACT_NUMBER is unique in A, but not unique in B?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yep, primarily the CONTACT_NUMBER should be unique before applying the left join

Comment: Okay. CONTRACT_NUMBER is unique in A, but not unique in B. You want to select  B.AMT_INTEREST_INCOME for a CONTRACT_NUMBER, but there is more than one B.AMT_INTEREST_INCOME for a CONTRACT_NUMBER. Now, what exactly do you want to do about this? Do you want to select the sum of all its B.AMT_INTEREST_INCOME for a CONTRACT_NUMBER? Or what else?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner maybe I'll just average the B.AMT_INTEREST_INCOME column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per contract you want the average interest income from your datamart table, so aggregate your datamart data by contract and join this result to your sales data table.

```
SELECT
  sd.*,
  dm.avg_interest_income
FROM dm_sales.v_sales_dm_data sd
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT contract_number, AVG(amt_interest_income) AS avg_interest_income
  FROM dm_fin.fin_ltv_datamart
  GROUP BY contract_number
) dm ON dm.contract_number = sd.contract_number
WHERE sd.contract_state <> 'Cancelled' 
  AND sd.cnt_signed = 1 
  AND sd.loan_type = 'Consumer Loan'
  AND sd.dtime_signature >= DATE '2022-08-01'
  AND sd.dtime_signature < DATE '2022-09-01'
ORDER BY sd.dtime_signature;
```